# Envío a varias direcciones de email mediante PHP fallido usando PHP Mailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

Quiero que me lleguen correos electrónicos a dos direcciones y por eso le coloco que me mande a:

```
<?php
    if (condicion) { 
            $strTo = array('mail1'); 
    } else { 
            $strTo = array('mail2','mail3'); 
            }
```

- Cuando se cumple la condición, llegan bien al `mail1`.
- Cuando no se cumple, antes de agregar el `mail3`, llegaba bien al `mail2`.
- Ahora que agregué el `mail3`, sólo llega al `mail3`. Dejó de llegar al `mail2`.

¿Por qué puede ser?

Agrego cómo leo el `$strTo`:

```
<?php
  foreach($strTo as $receiver){
        $email->AddAddress( $receiver );
      }

   $email->send();
```

Comment: ¿Cómo lees `$strTo` al momento de enviar el email? [Edita la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/175885/edit) poniendo esa parte del código. Todo parece indicar que usas un bucle o algo donde sólo que queda con el último elemento del array.

Comment: Como dice el manual de [mail() manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php), El parametro to puede ir delimitado por comas por cada destinatario.

Comment: Ahi edite la pregunta con mas info, gracias!

Comment: Prueba a ponerlo así: `if (condicion) { $strTo = 'mail1'; } else { $strTo = 'mail2','mail3'; }` Por cierto, ¿estás usando PHPMailer o simplemente la función `mail` nativa de PHP?

Comment: Estoy utilizando PHP mailer, pero si coloco $strTo = 'mail2', 'mail3'; me da error. Que valor tomaria strTo en ese caso? No logro entender

Comment: Ya, es que debiste decir desde el principio que usabas PHPMailer. Para enviar a varios destinatarios sería como lo estás haciendo. Ahora bien, no sé si el fallo sea debido a las comillas que usas en el array. En lugar de esto: `‘` usa la comilla simple normal: `'` y prueba.

Comment: La comilla que uso es ' '

Comment: Pues debería funcionarte así. ¿Podrías mostrar un `var_dump($strTo);`?

Comment: array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "mail2" [1]=> string(5) "mail3" }

Comment: Pedro prueba con direcciones reales, poniendo por ejemplo tu propia dirección dos veces, o dos direcciones que sean tuyas. El código debería funcionar, como lo tienes ahora o bien según la respuesta dada, agregando un nombre de destinatario. Prueba con un bloque `try... catch`, para que te informe de eventuales errores.

Comment: ¿Podrías activar la depuración de PHPMailer? ¿Usas SMTP? Prueba con `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;`. Por favor, pega el log (censurando lo que veas oportuno) en tu pregunta. Gracias.

Comment: Por cierto, ¿qué versión de PHPMailer estás usando? ¿La instalas/actualizas mediante `composer` o lo haces manualmente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba de este modo, agregando un segundo parámetro en el array.

Este parámetro es opcional, por lo que encuentro extraño que el código falle como lo tenías originalmente. En ese sentido sería interesante ver un `var_dump` del array original.

En el código cambia los valores del array por valores reales.

```
if (condicion) { 
    $strTo = array("nombre1@example.com"=>"Nombre1"); 
}else{
    $strTo = array("nombre2@example.com"=>"Nombre2", "nombre3@example.com"=>"Nombre3" ); 
}
```

Puedes usar un bloque `try... catch` para saber qué error estarías teniendo:

```
$email = new PHPMailer(true);      // Passing `true` enables exceptions
try {
    /*Poner el código que falte */

    //...
    /*Agregar destinatarios */
    foreach ($strTo as $e_mail=>$nombre){
        $email->AddAddress($e_mail, $nombre);    
    }

    $email->send();
    echo 'Mensaje enviado con éxito';

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Mensaje no enviado. Mailer Error: ', $email->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Comment: Si hago un var_dump de $mail te serviria? Sigue sin funcionarme

Comment: @A. Cedano una observación has arrastrado $email->send del ejemplo dónde debería ser $mail para PHPMailer, se mezcla con tu variable $email.

Comment: @Pedro puede ser por lo que ha apuntado Carmen en su comentario: una confusión de variables. Prueba con el código cómo está ahora, editado. Verifica que la variable del objeto PHPMailer se llama `$email` en todas partes y que la variable extraída del array se llama `$e_mail`

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente en phpMailer la función `AddAddress(email, name)` está descrita para contener dos parámetros, revisa como está en tu clase `phpMailer` por si está modificada. El nombre del receptor es opcional y si no está no lo usa, pero es necesario indicar que está vacío si vas a hacer el envío a varias direcciones.

Prueba a implementarlo de este modo:

```
foreach($strTo as $receiver){
   $email->AddAddress($receiver, '');
}
```

Comment: Disiento de tu respuesta. El parámetro `$name` es opcional y se sustituye por una cadena vacía en caso de no proporcionarse un valor (tal y como tú haces explícitamente). Puedes verlo en su [código fuente](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/5c9d3c548497390822369516691139f0a724b621/src/PHPMailer.php#L932): `public function addAddress($address, $name = '')`.

Comment: @OscarGarcia Me refería a que si es necesario indicar que está vacío si no se le pasa un valor, he corregido el modo de expresarlo para que no lleve a confusión, de ahí que en mi respuesta indique que se pase el campo en este caso vacío. Proporcionar un valor vacío es proporcionar un valor al fin y al cabo.

Comment: El problema es que tu respuesta y el código de la pregunta es el mismo tal y como te indiqué en mi comentario. Proporcionar un valor de cadena vacía 
para el parámetro `$name` o no hacerlo es equivalente (ni mejora ni empeora en nada el programa) y, obviamente, no arreglará su problema.

Comment: En mi experiencia añadir el valor vacío explicitamente funciona.

Comment: Y si lo quitas también funciona, ¿verdad? Entonces quizá el problema raíz no sea proporcionar o no el parámetro, debe ser otro. ¿Has pensado en esa posibilidad? Por lo tanto creo que hay que seguir buscando el origen del problema.

Comment: De ahí el concepto de probar a implementar la función con ambos parámetros sobre el código de la pregunta proporcionado, ya que el resto le funcionaba. ¿Puede ser otra la causa? por supuesto, asi que está aportado como una opción a probar en el momento en que se realizó la pregunta. Me parece perfecto que disientas.

Comment: La realidad es que añadiendo el valor vacìo funciona. Y sin añadirlo, no. 
Realmente es un error porque es un parametro opcional, pero estimo que si no lo ponemos, falla algo. Gracias!